# MySQL statement with ">" or "<" parameter

Tags: php, mysql, nette

Is there a way how to fetch all data from table where number is higher than something.

In my case I am using UNIX time in database to be able to easily compare data. Right now I would like to count every login which is higher then current UNIX time minus 24 hours.

Is there a way how I can write it? I was thinking about something like this but not sure how can I write SQL statement with `<` or `>`.

```
function getDailyOnline()
{
    return $this->db->table('users')
        ->where('last_login', $post->id);
}
```

I need SQL command, don't need to use Nette Framework as I do in my "example".

Comment: Where does `$this->db->table()` and `where()` come from?

Comment: The ORM you are using probably provides a way, but since we don't know what that ORM is, we can't tell you what that way is.

Comment: this is Nette framework, don't care about that, I'm fine with basic SQL command

Comment: `->where('last_login > ?', $post->id);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply try this:

```
$this->db->table('users')->where('last_login > ', $post->id);
```

Comment: Is this missing a `?` in the `where` clause?

Comment: It's nette database. It allows you to not write ?, it will append them automatically.

Comment: This is actually really good point, thanks for that. how ever at the end based on this and other questions i create my final answer:
  `return $this->db->fetchPairs('SELECT COUNT(*) last_login FROM users WHERE last_login > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (24 * 60 * 60)');`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM users
 WHERE last_login > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (24 * 60 * 60));
```

Comment: please edit your answer and include some explanation about why this solves the OP problem. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better.

Comment: @Barranka I don't see anything that would specifically require explanation; it's pretty basic SQL that directly responds to OP's question. If OP has any particular problems with my answer, I'd be happy to explain, or retract if necessary.

Comment: Thumb up, your answer was usefull for me :)

Answer (score 2):

you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT *
  FROM users
  WHERE last_login > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (24 * (3600)));
```

This will select all the row with a `last_login` older than 24 hours(**1day**).

Comment: Thumb up, your answer was usefull for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and you can go for this solution:

```
$this->db->table("users")
    ->where('last_login > ', $post->id);
```

cheers